# Heredoc for html in php

Tags: php, heredoc

The heredoc isn't working for the following code

```
    $html = <<<HTML 
             <video width="$width" height="$height" controls preload autoplay >
             <source src="$video_url_direct" type="video/mp4" /> 
    <object id="flowplayer" width="$width" height="$height" data="$player_url" type="application/x-shockwave-flash">

        <param name="allowfullscreen" value="true" />
        <param name="wmode" value="transparent" />
        <param name="flashvars" value='config={"clip":"$video_url", "plugins": {"controls": {"autoHide" : false} }}' />

    </object></video>
HTML;
```

Also can i use a heredoc for the `flashvars` value as well (i.e a heredoc inside another heredoc).

Comment: In what way isn't it working? And why would you need to use a here-doc inside another here-doc? It's already expanding variables when you're in the first here-doc, why do you need another level?

Comment: @Barmar I am getting a syntax error with the code above.I want to avoid double quotes inside the json for `config=`

Comment: You have an extra space after `<<<HTML`. Get rid of it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have a space after `<<<HTML`:

```
$html = <<<HTML 
        here---^
```

This is causing the syntax error. The token has to be followed immediately by a newline.

Comment: remove it but then the whole page becomes a comment why is `HTML;` not taking effect

Comment: I can't reproduce that. Are you ever doing `echo $html;` to show what you assigned?