# if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') don't work

Tags: php

I can't explain it, because I'm studying the book learning PHP and I went to test this example and it doesn't work at all.

```
<?php
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
    print "hello, ". $_POST['my_name'];
} 
else {
    print<<<_HTML_
         <form method="post" action="$_SERVER[PHP_SELF]">
         Your name: <input type="text" name="my name">
         <br>
         <input type="submit" value="Say Hello">
        </form>
        _HTML_;
}
?>
```

Comment: What exactly is the problem?

Comment: Could you describe what happens when "it doesn't work at all"? Does your computer not switch on?

Comment: Your [HEREDOC](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc) for HTML is incorrect please review https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29940339/heredoc-for-html-in-php

Comment: I use replit.com to test the examples and answer questions, so I took and re-typed this example, which is a simple form. When I try to run it to see the code in action, it ends up giving this error->

 [Tue Apr 6 19:19:51 2021] 172.18.0.1:45474 [500]: / - syntax error, unexpected end of file in /home/runner/my-codes-test/index.php on line 16

Comment: [Tue Apr  6 19:24:21 2021] 172.18.0.1:54074 [500]: / - syntax error, unexpected '<<' (T_SL) in /home/runner/my-codes-test/index.php on line 8

Comment: What does `var_dump($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']);` says you? Please put some effort in debbuging.

Comment: There's been an unusually high number of HEREDOC problems lately on SO. I wonder if there's a tutorial floating around with it claiming it can solve all the worlds problems. More of an observation than anything

Answer (score 2):

As said in the comments your HEREDOC (the `<<<HTML` and `HTML;` parts) is incorrectly formed. Below is the corrected one so you can see the difference.

```php
<?php
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
    print "hello, " . $_POST['my_name'];
} else {
    print<<<HTML
         <form method="post" action="$_SERVER[PHP_SELF]">
         Your name: <input type="text" name="my name">
         <br>
         <input type="submit" value="Say Hello">
        </form>
HTML;
}
```

Below is a screen for a working example on replit.com as the OP is using.

[image: Image of working example on Repl.it which the OP is using to test]

Comment: You're welcome. If I've helped please accept the answer if it solves your problem. If not we can continue discussing